# get last inserted row id in ebean with sqlupdate

Tags: sql, oracle, ebean

If I am using ebean sqlupdate to do insert into Oracle in Java

```
    Transaction tx = Ebean.beginTransaction();
    try {

Transaction tx = Ebean.beginTransaction();
try {

    String sqlString = "INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1001,'Nichols', 'Alexandra', '17 Maple Drive', "+ "'Nashua', 'NH','03062', SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE (-71.48923,42.72347,NULL), NULL, NULL))";
    SqlUpdate query = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(sqlString);
    query.execute();
    String sqlQuery =
            "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity'";
    SqlQuery query2 = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sqlQuery);

    List<SqlRow> list = query2.findList();
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
} finally {
  tx.commit();
}
```

It gives error

```
[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ORA-00936: missing expression
  Query was:
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity'

]
```

How do I get the id of last inserted row?

Comment: use order by desc in select query

Comment: @XING That will only work if the Primary Key is an auto incremented integer.

Answer (score 0):

After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement is completed, @@IDENTITY contains the last identity value that is generated by the statement.

But this is in sql So i think you should create the USP and you can return the last inserted record id as outparm from the USP

```
   String sqlString = "INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1001,'Nichols', 'Alexandra', '17 Maple Drive', "+ "'Nashua', 'NH','03062', SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE (-71.48923,42.72347,NULL), NULL, NULL))";
   SqlUpdate query = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(sqlString);
   query.execute();
   SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';
```